# Running a meteor app as part of a wider django project

Tags: django, mongodb, meteor

I'm currently working on a project which would require some realtime functionalities such as Multi-user chatrooms etc.

Ideally, I’m looking to have meteor run the chat application(on a different port) and mongodb act as message broker to the django back-end which would take care of user registration , management and everything 'non-realtime' related.

This would involve setting up a reverse-proxy which would redirect to a different port based on the url (please let me know if i'm wrong in this)

Would this be possible(or even advisable)? Another option would be to implement the same with tornado. but I have no experience with building tornado-based apps and rather do this with a framework I’m comfortable with.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have Django serve the Meteor front-end while providing access to its data using [django-ddp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ddp/), giving you some distinct advantages:

- Continue to serve your existing Django project/apps.
- No extra services or ports to manage.
- Scale out by simply adding more front-end Python/Django servers (server to server IPC is done via the *existing database connection*).
- Use `django.contrib.auth` user accounts in your Meteor app.
- Familiar Python/Django code (no "callback" style such as with Tornado).
- Use time-tested, trusted relational databases.
- Use Django migrations to effectively manage schema changes.

There's a [Gitter chat room](https://gitter.im/commoncode/django-ddp) where I can give you assistance if you need it.

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of django-ddp.

Comment: It's good that you're disclaiming your affiliation, but this post is only a half-answer: it would be better if you could add some detail of how it should be done.

Comment: @ArtOfCode -- The question only asked if it would be possible (or advisable).  I've answered in the affirmative and even given some rationale, but never did the OP ask *how* to achieve their goal.

Point taken though, an example would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

A meteor application is more than capable of handling the user registration flow and many other things. Why not just build the application entirely in meteor? Your application sounds like a perfect candidate for meteor, with realtime interaction with your database at the core.

The other option would be to use [swampdragon](http://swampdragon.net/) which adds realtime data binding within django. It allows for simple bi directional communication between the server and the client. Again, essential for a chat application. It nice and easy to get setup and running as well.

Are there any specific reasons to not implementing your application in one framework alone?

Comment: I'm actually very new to Mongodb - That's one of the reasons why I am sorta reluctant to go full meteor.

Comment: Also, if there needs to be a feature which doesnt necessary require async (like profile views etc etc) - I can integrate django right? am i right in thinking that all i need to do is serve the pages in a different port?